# GLSL, Shader has some array limit?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I create 1000 size vec3 array, but it shows nothing on glut window
when I resize the array to 128. it will show
I think it has some limit on my Graphic card.

what can I do to avoid this limit?

```
uniform vec3 cir[128]; // can show something

uniform vec3 cir[1000]; // shows nothing
```

I need pass at least 500 cir to shader.

Answer (score 4):

Uniforms have been extended tu support large arrays through [GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt). If you can't afford to use this extension you might consider using a one-dimensional texture instead.